# Update longtext field in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to update a longtext type field called 'comment' using a simple sql query in mysql client like this :

```
Update mytable set comment='Test' where id = 1;
```

But i'm getting this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'comment='Test' where id = 1' at line 1
```

Am i missing something ?, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it gets solved with this:

```
update mytable as a set a.comment='Test' where id = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`comment` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html), if you want to have a table/field with that name, you have to quote it (or use the `table.fieldname` syntax, in case of a field). default in mysql is the backtick for that, so:

```
 update mytable set `comment`='Test' where id = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, already quoted and even changed it for another word but still get the same error, any idea why ?

Comment: @jsanchezs I can't tell, unless you update your question, code and error message